# new java.sql.Date(0) not corresponding to 00:00:00 1 January 1970

Tags: java, date, timezone, epoch

The code below:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class FooMain {
    private static final DateFormat DF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'");

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(DF.format(new Date(0)));
    }
}
```

prints out:

```
1970-01-01T01:00Z
```

Should'nt it have been `1970-01-01T00:00Z` instead? I understand that Unix Epoch time is always unambiguous and we don't have to worry about timezones, but here's my timezone in case it matters:

```
$ cat /etc/timezone 
Europe/Madrid
```

Comment: From the documentation of `java.util.Date`: "[...]represent the specified number of milliseconds since [...] January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 **GMT**." and Spain's time zone is GMT+1 so that output is correct.

Comment: Also, don't confuse `java.sql.Date` with `java.util.Date`. The former extends the latter and is supposed to contain info about the date only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new Date(0)` *does* correspond to `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`. The issue is that, by default, `DateFormat` will print the date in your *system timezone*. Set the timezone on your formatter to GMT:

```
DF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(DF.format(new Date(0))); // outputs: 1970-01-01T00:00Z
```

Comment: My bad. Copied the snippet from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date and thought that "Z" corresponds to Zulu timezone (which it does, but it is hardcoded so one has to set the timezone as per your answer).

Comment: No worries. I completely missed that the format had a hard-coded `'Z'` on it, as well =p

Answer (score 1):

You have to `.setTimeZone()` your `SimpleDateFormat`; by default, the time zone is the system time zone:

```
final SimpleDateFormat fmt 
    = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'");
fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

System.out.println(fmt.format(new Date(0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Recommended
        Instant epoch = Instant.EPOCH;
        System.out.println(epoch);

        // Alternatively,
        epoch = Instant.ofEpochMilli(0);
        System.out.println(epoch);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>